# Please anyone tell me what i do that my website display date and time not get reset on refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, anyone, tell me what I do that my website displays date and time does not get reset on refreshing the page.
what I add extra is that my date timer does not get reset on refreshing the page

$(window).on("load", function () {

```
var clock;

  clock = $(".clock").FlipClock({


    clockFace: "DailyCounter",

    autoStart: false,

    callbacks: {

      stop: function () {

        $(".message").html("The IDO has been started!");
      },
    },
  });
  


  clock.setTime(30000);

  clock.setCountdown(true);

  clock.start();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Onload gets triggered when refreshing the site. You‘d have to save the state outside the scope of the function. If you‘re using a statis webpage and you simply added the script to the head, then the script always gets executed on page load. Look into webservers. Node.js with express library for example.